# What is the value of $\angle x$

Tags: geometry

Can any one help with this problem:what is value of $\angle x$
[image]

Comment: Did you take into account the fact that you have rectangular triangles and that the sums of angles in a triangle is Pi ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $30^\circ$.

**Proof**: Let this big triangle be $ABC$ where $$\angle ABC=20^\circ+60^\circ, \angle ACB=30^\circ+50^\circ, \angle BAC=20^\circ.$$

Also, let $D,E$ be the inner point on $AC, AB$ respectively.

Now, take a point $F$ on $AB$ such that $BD=BF$. Also, take a point $G$ on $DF$ such that $AD=AG.$ (Note that $G$ is outside of $ABC$)

Also, prove that the triangles $AGF, DBC$ are congruent. Then finally prove that $FD=FE$.